# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Point

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar, libgdx

I am using Android Studio for developing a LibGDX based game for android devices. I have imported "Point" from java.awt.Point. I have tested it using the DesktopLauncher. It works fine.

Issue : When I loaded it in Android device, I am getting error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Point" when I reach the line below. Please advice on how to solve this .

```
            Point p=new  Point(toyCells[i][0] + toyCellsAdjecentCells[j][0],
                               toyCells[i][1] + toyCellsAdjecentCells[j][1]);
```

Comment: Including more of your code might help to figure out where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you use `com.badlogic.gdx.math.GridPoint2D` instead of `java.awt.Point` ?

Answer (score 4):

This is because Android does not support `awt` (or `Swing`). These are graphic libraries to be used when developing computer applications. Try to use

```
android.graphics.Point
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

milez has the correct answer. Android doesn't have the Point class that you're using for the DesktopLauncher.

However, one thing you should note: LibGDX is supposed to work in a device-independent manner. This means the code shouldn't require changing between devices. Therefore, you need to find a solution that is device-independent.

You have two options:

You could create your own MyPoint class that has an X and Y integer field in it. That's pretty simple, and it has next to no overhead.

You could also use the Point-like class LibGDX provides called Vector2. This class is guaranteed to work on all devices:

```
Vector2 point = new Vector2(x, y);
```

For this option, calling point.x would give you the float representation of whatever X you passed in. This float value would have to be casted to an integer if you wanted to use it in an array, however.

```
my_x = my_array[(int) point.x];
```

It also gives you some useful math options like translate(dx, dy) or angle(). Use this one if you're interested in doing more options than just storing two integer values.